# Subscripts and the `\mathrm{}` command

Tags: definition, mathrm

Consider a library of symbol definitions.  Which of the following uses of the `\mathrm{}` command is preferred?

```
\def\phosphoricacid{\mathrm{H_{3}PO_{4}}}%
\def\phosphoricacid{\mathrm{H}_{3}\mathrm{PO}_{4}}%
```

Are they both not ideal?  Should an alternative to `\def{}` be used?

Comment: For sure you don’t want to use `\def`, but rather `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you see value in performing a task that's the functional equivalent of reinventing the wheel, you may want to load one of the LaTeX packages that make it simple and straightforward to input the names of chemical compounds. For instance, the `mhchem` package provides the user macro `\ce`, with which one can write `\ce{H2O}` and `\ce{H3PO4}`. Observe that `\ce` may be used in both text and math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\phosphoricacidA{\mathrm{H_{3}PO_{4}}}
\def\phosphoricacidB{\mathrm{H}_{3}\mathrm{PO}_{4}}
\usepackage{mhchem} % for '\ce' macro
\begin{document}
$\phosphoricacidA$ $\phosphoricacidB$ \ce{H3PO4}
\end{document}
```

FWIW, I'd say that `\phosphoricacidB` is more straightforward to parse than `\phosphoricacidA` is.